# cy.request doesn't allowing me to go to next UI test cases

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, cypress

Trying to integrate both UI & API test cases

Created two files:

1. API test --> DO Login and writing token & saving it to fixture file
2. Spec test -->Do REAL Login by using username and password and once test case pass then in next test first get the response by using cy.request using token which saved by step1. Based on response keys search the data in search bar

**API Test File:**

```
it("Login Request API",function(){

        cy.request({
            method:"POST",
            url: POST URL,
            headers:{
             "content-type" : "application/json"
            },
            body : {
             "email": USER NAME,
             "password": PASSWORD
            },
            log: true
        }).then((response) => {
             // Parse JSON the body.
             expect(response.status).to.equal(200)
             let resbody = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.body));
            cy.writeFile("File Path to store response",resbody)
         })
    });
```

**Cypress version: 3.8.3**

Once above test is executed then it redirect to first test . Not going to further tests

Comment: You need to refer to https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Usage and create a `cy.getToken` command for `step 1`.

Comment: Ideally it should not be the case! Here, I have mentioned only one example but for all multiple api's i can't do the same. I don't want to create Test data for few features as UI is there only for managing purpose and actions can be done on mobile. So By using cy.request I want to generate a response and using that response wanted to do further operations

Comment: Why it is routing me on first step once That request is executed

Comment: Can you add some test screenshots to help me understand what is happening with your current approach.

Comment: To make it simple, Add given file as spec1 (POST CALL) and in spec2 only do cy.visit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **Cypress Version 3.8.3**: You may need to check the path of the new file you are trying to create. it is by default within the 'fixture' folder.

```
cy.request({
    method:"POST",
    url: POST URL,
    headers: {
      "content-type" : "application/json"
    },
    body : {
      "email": USER NAME,
      "password": PASSWORD
    },
    log: true
}).then((response) => {
    // Parse JSON the body.
    expect(response.status).to.equal(200);
    cy.writeFile("<path>/api.json", response.body); // <path> is with respect to cypress/fixture folder
});
```

From my test:

[image: Test screenshot]

Comment: To take whole body in json when I applied give solution ,It is giving me an error : " Cannot read property 'body' of undefined"

Comment: I am using Cypress 3.8.3 version

Comment: Works fine when I added xhr.body instead of xhr.response.body.Thanks!!!

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your cypress version. Please do mark the answer as accepted if it helped :)