# how to store access token generated using cypress (request) so I can use this as Auth header to call other API's

Tags: cypress

How can I access the token parsed from JSON response

```
const getToken = () =>
    cy.request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/generateToken'
    });
        .its('body')
        .then((response) => {
            JSON.parse(response)
            token = token['accessToken']  //How can I access this token value to use in other It tests?
        })
```

Comment: Does this solution help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62214550/cy-request-doesnt-allowing-me-to-go-to-next-ui-test-cases/62217505#62217505?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this approach:

```
const getToken = () => {
  cy.request({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/generateToken'
  }).its('body').then(function(response) {
    json = JSON.parse(response)
    this.token = json['accessToken']
  })
}

// Afterwards...
it('should xxxxxxxx xxx xxx', () => {
  console.log(this.token)
});
```

Please note that accessing aliases as properties with `this.*` will not work if you use arrow functions `=>`, this is the reason why I used `function`.